# Finding connected components using OpenCV

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, edge-detection, connected-components

I am trying to find and separate all edges in an edge detected image using python OpenCV. The edges can be in a form of contour but they don't have to. I just want all connected edges pixels to be grouped together. So technically the algorithm may procedurally sound like this:

1. For each edge pixel, find a neighbouring (connected) edge pixel and add it to a current subdivision of the image, until you can't find one anymore.
2. Then move on to the next unchecked edge pixel and start a new subdivision and do 1) again.

I have looked through `cv.findContours` but the results wasn't satisfying, maybe because it was intended for contours (enclosed edges) rather than free-ended ones. Here are the results:

Original Edge Detected:

[image]

After Contour Processing:

[image]

I expected the five edges would each be grouped into its own subdivision of the image, but apparently the cv2.findContours function breaks 2 of the edges even further into subdivisions which I don't want.

Here is the code I used to save these 2 images:

```
    def contourForming(imgData):
      cv2.imshow('Edge', imgData)
      cv2.imwrite('EdgeOriginal.png', imgData)
      contours = cv2.findContours(imgData, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
      cv2.imshow('Contours', imgData)
      cv2.imwrite('AfterFindContour.png', imgData)
      cv2.waitKey(0)
      pass
```

There are restrictions to my implementation, however. I have to use Python 2.7 and OpenCV2. I cannot use any other revision or languages besides these. I say this because I know OpenCV 2 has a connectedComponent function using C++. I could have used that but the problem is, I cannot use it due to certain limitations.

So, any idea how I should approach the problem?

Comment: you could try to cv::dilate the edges before contour extraction but that might alter the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#findcontours) is the correct approach, you're simply doing it wrong.

Take a closer look to the documentation:

> **Note:** Source image is modified by this function.

Your *"After Contour Processing"* image is in fact the *garbage* result from `findContours`. Because of this, if you want the original image to be intact after the call to `findContours`, it's common practice to pass a cloned image to the function.

The *meaningful* result of `findContours` is in `contours`. You need to draw them using `drawContours`, usually on a new image.

This is the result I get:

[image]

with the following C++ code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Load the grayscale image
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Prepare the result image, 3 channel, same size as img, all black
    Mat3b res(img.rows, img.cols, Vec3b(0,0,0));

    // Call findContours
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(img.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    // Draw each contour with a random color
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        drawContours(res, contours, i, Scalar(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255));
    }

    // Show results
    imshow("Result", res);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

It should be fairly easy to port to Python (I'm sorry but I can't give you Python code, since I cannot test it). You can also have a look at the specific [OpenCV - Python tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html#gsc.tab=0) to check how to correctly use `findContours` and `drawContours`.

Comment: Thanks! I think it works now. I didn't know the documentation for OpenCV 3.0.0 that you gave ( [link](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html#gsc.tab=0) ) works for OpenCV 2.7 too.